# Multi-Column Text Display in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display text in 2 column.

**Ex.** I have large String , First string add in first column and after getting end of screen height , text should be add on second column. like news papaer.

First first column fill thenn second.

But output is not come proper . below is output image.

[image]

java code

```
final TextView tvl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textl);
final TextView tvr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textr);
final String text = "sdf";
tvl.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextMeasure(text,tvl,tvr);
    }
    });

private void TextMeasure(String text,
TextView tvl,TextView tvr) {
// Get number of lines of text that will fit on the screen
int linesPerScreen = tvl.getHeight()/(tvl.getLineHeight() + (int)tvl.getLineSpacingExtra());
// Measure how much text will fit across the TextView
Paint paint = tvl.getPaint();
int textWidth = paint.breakText(text, 0, text.length(),
true, tvl.getWidth(), null);
// Total amount of text to fill the TextView is
// approximately:
int totalText = textWidth * linesPerScreen;
String leftText = text.substring(0,totalText);
String rightText = text.substring(totalText,
text.length());
tvl.setText(leftText);
tvr.setText(rightText);
}
```

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the logcat output

Comment: Here is getLineSpacingExtra red line .

Comment: [getLineSpacingExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineSpacingExtra()) was added in API level 16. What is your minimum API Level ?

Comment: @AshwiniBhangi: thnks. any other way to use beofre 16 ?

Comment: Using setLineSpacing() and then calcucate the extra yourself

Comment: I tried this not working

Comment: Post the code that you have tried please

Comment: Above code. I just change level now

Comment: change both textview's android:layout_width="0dp" as you are using layout_weight